# Why is this insert statement causing an error?

Tags: trigger, unit-test, update, insert

Could anybody enlighten me as to why this piece of code is causing an error when I try to run it in Execute Anonymous?

This is the code I am running from my test class:

```
List<Case> newCases = new List<Case>();

        for (Integer i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Case c = new Case(CountryWebFormText__c ='CA', Newsletter__c = TRUE);
            System.debug(c);
            newCases.add(c);
            System.debug(newCases);
        }
        insert newCases;
```

And this is the Error message that I am receiving:

> "Line: 10, Column: 1 System.DmlException: Insert failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
>   WebToCaseCountry: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.StringException: Invalid id: CA Trigger.WebToCaseCountry: line
>   39, column 1: []"

Here is the trigger for reference:

```
trigger WebToCaseCountry on Case (after insert)
{
    //Update Cases and Contact fields
    List<Case>  caseList = [SELECT Id, CountryWebFormText__c, Newsletter__c, Country_of_Origin__c  
                               FROM Case WHERE CountryWebFormText__c != NULL];
    List<Area__c> areaList = [SELECT Name, Id From Area__c];
    List<Case>  casesToUpdate = new List<Case>();
    for(Case caseObj : caseList)
    {
        for(Area__c a : areaList)
        {
            if(caseObj.Newsletter__c == TRUE && caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && 
               a.Name == caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c)
            {
                caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c = a.Name;
                CaseObj.Contact.Country__c = a.Name;
                casesToUpdate.add(caseObj);
            }
        }            
    }

    update casesToUpdate;

}
```

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: What is in the line 39 in your WebToCaseCountry trigger?

Comment: @TugceSirin This is what is on line 39: caseObj.Country_of_Origin__c = a.Name;

Comment: Hi @James my WebToCaseCountry code is included above

Comment: Can you comment out this line and try again?         CaseObj.Contact.Country__c = a.Name;

Comment: Commented it out and I still get the same error but on a different line "Line: 2, Column: 1
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, WebToCaseCountry: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: CA Trigger.WebToCaseCountry: line 37, column 1: []" And line 37 is: if(caseObj.Newsletter__c == TRUE && caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && a.Id == caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c)

Comment: The line `CaseObj.Contact.Country__c = a.Name;` will fail because the Contact reference is not retrieved in your initial SOQL; furthermore the `update casesToUpdate` won't save the update to the Contact. Contact updates will require a separate DML statement

Answer (score 1):

I think it's caused by the mapping, your field Country_of_Origin__c is a lookup field so you should map it to a.Id and not a.Name

Comment: It didn't make a difference but thanks @melmoussaoui

Comment: @Nik I updated my response

Comment: I changed a.Name to a.Id assuming that is what I was meant to do but I still have the same error. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Ok, I think you are mapping or comparing 2 different  types of fields String/Id 
from your last comment, I think it's the Case.CountryWebFormText__c and Area__c.Id

Comment: I need to match Area__c field Name to Case field CountryWebFormText__c. If they match I need to update the Country_of_Origin__c field on Case and the Country__c field on Contact

Comment: In this case, in  your code should compare caseObj.CountryWebFormText__c != NULL && a.Name and not a.Id ? and if the Country_of_Origin__c is a lookup field you should map it to a.Id and not the a.Name.

Comment: I also think it is about lookup field issue. You need to check what kind of object reference is Country_of_Origin__c field and put a correct id value in there. If it is not Area__c object reference then it is normal to get the same error.

Comment: Should I be mapping String and Area then by creating a Map?